# Image reduction when it is not clicked - to speed up a website

Tags: wordpress, image, web

I'm a beginner programmer. So I want to speed up an image-heavy website, it has a lot of 1000x750 images (when it is clicked - so enlarged), but when the website loaded and you don't click on an image, it is only 200x150. However, the website loads the full size of the image.

How can I do that the website load only the 200x150 version, and only loads the big image when it is clicked?

By the way, the website is wordpress.

Many thanks - and sorry because of the lame question :(

Comment: by googling it I found this https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load-xt/

Answer (score 0):

When inserting an image via the content editor, you have the ability to select the image size you want to use. The available (default) image sizes will be 'full', 'large', 'medium', and 'thumbnail'. You can also set the image to link to the full size image as well.

You have the ability to register custom image sizes in a theme or plugin. This can give you alternate image sizes to use. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

When outputting images via php in templates, you should take advantage of functions such as [wp_get_attachment_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) or [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) which allow you to output images and select the 'size'. Again, sizes are the default sizes and your registered custom image sizes.

The advantage of outputting images this way, is that it also takes advantage of [responsive images](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/) - where WordPress will automatically add srcset tags to the  with the various sizes for multiple devices.

If you want to be able to click on the image and have it pop-up the full image, you'll need to use javascript - or a plugin - to add this feature.